# AngularJS UI-Router multiple pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angular-ui-router

As Angular is SPA that's terrific, but what if I need some other page not related to index.html, how is realised by UI-Router states with different ui-views?

For example, I have **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="npAdmin">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
   <header>
      <data-user-profile class="user-profile"></data-user-profile>
  </header>

  <section class="content-wrapper">
      <aside data-main-menu></aside>
      <div class="main-content" data-ui-view></div>
  </section>

  <footer class="row"></footer>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**:

```
var app = angular.module('npAdmin', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
    })
    .state('crm', {
        url: '/crm',
        templateUrl: '/app/crm/crm.html',
        controller: 'CrmCtrl'
    })
...
```

Now I need **login.html** which is totally different from index.html (don't need index's header, footer, sidebar) but config stateProvider only looks to index.html ui-view and changes content to it by states. How to combine login.html?

It seems not that hard, but I don't get it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you expected, it is not so difficult, there is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TahGIArycr2eHayoOpEA?p=preview).

The trick is to move the common stuff for all views inside of the specific template e.g. `common.html` and create the abstract state. Other words, the `index.html` will remain clean:

```
<body>

    <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>
```

And its previous content *(content of the `index.html`)* would be moved to `common.html`. The state definition could look like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('common', {
    templateUrl: 'tpl.common.html',
    abstract: true,
  })
  .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    parent: 'common',
    ...
  })
  .state('crm', { 
    url: '/crm',
    parent: 'common',
    ...
  })
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.login.html',
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/crm');
```

What is **interesting** *(I'd say)* is that we introduced **abstract** state, **without url**. So the all **current logic will remain**, just the abstract will play role of a **layout template**.

Check more here: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TahGIArycr2eHayoOpEA?p=preview)

Comment: Now I know how to use abstract state property. Thank you.

Comment: Great to see that;) `ui-router` is incredible and really powerful... Enjoy it ;)

Comment: @KillABug I would suggest, issue question. Show more details. You will surelly get an answer. Or let me know I can check it as well. Comment is not suitable for investigating why is your code not working... Does it make sense?

Comment: @KillABug If I will know, I will help. But your question will target more guys than must me, so you will get answer... I am sure

Comment: @RadimKöhler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073389/loading-angular-js-internal-routes-and-controllers

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem before, refer to [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356919/single-page-application-deep-linking-with-login-page) if you're interested. In that link, I also handled `returnUrl` and `401 http status code` in case the user is not authorized.

In your case, I suggest you design your application like this:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="npAdmin">
<head>
...
</head>
<body data-ui-view>

</body>
...
</html>
```

main.html:

```
  <header>
      <data-user-profile class="user-profile"></data-user-profile>
  </header>

  <section class="content-wrapper">
      <aside data-main-menu></aside>
      <div class="main-content" data-ui-view></div>
  </section>

  <footer class="row"></footer>
```

login.html

(include your html for this view)

App.js:

```
var app = angular.module('npAdmin', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('login',{
       url:"/login",
       templateUrl: '/app/login.html',
       controller: 'LoginCtrl'
     })
    .state('main',function(){
       url:"/",
       templateUrl: '/app/main.html',
       controller: 'MainCtrl',
       abstract: true //you could use abstract state or not depending on your design 
    })
    .state('main.dashboard', { //inherit from your main
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
    })
    .state('main.crm', { //inherit from your main
        url: '/crm',
        templateUrl: '/app/crm/crm.html',
        controller: 'CrmCtrl'
    })
```

**Explanation**:

As angular is SPA, your index.html should **cover all views** of your application. There are multiple ways to ensure that. In this example, the `login` **is also a state** in your application that is separated from your `main`. By utilizing state inheritance in angular router, you could further have child states in your `main` which are `dashboard` and `crm` in this case.

Comment: In addition to the above, if you're going to have a separate Login page make sure you implement an Authentication Check service. This way, if the user isn't logged in they'll be re-directed to the login page. See [this video](http://youtu.be/hqAyiqUs93c) for a basic implementation.

Comment: @Ed B: Sure, because that's not included in the question. And we will check that for all requests, not only for login page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very exhaustive answer but with some minor mistakes. Radim's solution with abstract state seems as perfect solution.

Comment: @swolfish: I did not test the code, I just gave the idea. And as I said, there are multiple ways to do that. It's just a matter of design.